# Изменение информации о файле

Tags: c#, файлы

Как изменить информацию о версии файла и версии продукта в `.exe`-файле?

К примеру изменить дату создания можно через `IO.File.SetCreationTime`, а как быть с остальной информацией?

P.S. Нужно изменить у скомпилированного файла, а не до его сборки.

Comment: Вам придётся возиться с античными ресурсами. При этом если файл подписан, вы ещё и измените контрольную сумму.

Comment: На контрольную сумму я не претендую.

Comment: Тьфу, нативными ресурсами. Т9 такое Т9.

Comment: File.SetCreationTime меняет запись в файловой системе, а не в потрохах экзешника.

Comment: @VladD, античные выглядели интереснее)))

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну что да, то да :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Воспользуйтесь низкоуровневыми вызовами Win32 API - подробнее по [ссылке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468915(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. Можно также использовать высокоуровневую обёртку над этими вызовами, которая распространяется в виде подключаемого [NuGet-пакета](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vestris.ResourceLib):

   `Install-Package Vestris.ResourceLib`

Пример использования этой библиотеки:

- **Получение** информации о ресурсах dll или exe

  ```
  string filename = "ConsoleApp1.exe"; // path to dll or exe
  VersionResource vr = new VersionResource();
  vr.LoadFrom(filename);

  StringFileInfo sfi = (StringFileInfo)vr["StringFileInfo"];
  foreach (var stringTableEntry in sfi.Default.Strings)
  {
      Console.WriteLine($"{stringTableEntry.Value.Key} = {stringTableEntry.Value.StringValue}");
  }
  ```

  //output:

  ```
  Comments = 
  CompanyName = 
  FileDescription = ConsoleApp1
  FileVersion = 1.0.0.0
  InternalName = ConsoleApp1.exe
  LegalCopyright = Copyright ©  2017
  LegalTrademarks = 
  OriginalFilename = ConsoleApp1.exe
  ProductName = ConsoleApp1
  ProductVersion = 1.0.0.0
  Assembly Version = 1.0.0.0
  ```
- **Запись** изменений обратно в файл сборки

  ```
  sfi["CompanyName"] = "New company name";
  sfi["ProductVersion"] = "1.1.1.2";
  sfi["LegalCopyright"] = "New copyright";

  vr.SaveTo(filename);
  ```

Остальная документация [тут](https://github.com/dblock/resourcelib#reference)

Comment: Спасибо, опробую